# reset animation using TweenAnimationBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have this fadeIn animation that I easily animated:

```
late AnimationController finalMsgController;
...
finalMsgController = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), vsync: this);
...
Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(100 * finalMsgController.value, 0),
      child: Text(
        'Too slow!',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
      ),
    );
```

In this case, I have this countdown not using any particular effect:

```
TweenAnimationBuilder<Duration>(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
      tween: Tween(
          begin: const Duration(seconds: 4), end: const Duration(seconds: 1)),
      onEnd: () {
        setState(() {
          countingDown = false;
        });
      },
      builder: (BuildContext context, Duration value, Widget? child) {
        final seconds = value.inSeconds % 60;

        return Text(
          '$seconds',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 100),
        );
      },
    );
```

Since in this case I don't have any controller, how should I restart it?

I also use animate_do package:

```
late AnimationController blackBGController;
...

FadeIn(
      manualTrigger: true,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      controller: (controller) => blackBGController = controller,
      child: Container(
        color: Helpers().colors['text'],
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
          child: Text(
            'Tap screen on 5 seconds!',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

so then, I do `blackBGController.reset()`

Comment: TweenAnimationBuilder is an ImplicitlyAnimatedWidgets so it's not the best idea, if you really want to control it try using an AnimatedBuilder with your own controller just like animate_do

Comment: I tried to use animate_do, but all the methods produce an effect. I just want to make a timer "without"any explicit animation, just some smooth change between numbers

Comment: TweenAnimationBuilder creates a controller for you, but I thunkg you would prefer to do that instead so you can control it at will, but if not what about changing the Tween when countingDown = false to go the other way

Comment: I ended up using animate_do package and it works pretty well. Only problem is when I use setState, it restarts some animations, not sure why. I opened an issue in the repo but maybe it's not related